# how can I inject a keep-alive into a websocket handler in akka-http?

Tags: scala, websocket, akka-stream, akka-http

I've written some code to communicate with a browser over websockets using akka-http 10.0.9. It works nicely, except that the connection times out. Although we're sending a constant stream of data to the client, the client isn't requesting anything for long periods of time.

I know the solution is to inject keep-alive messages into the incoming websocket source, like this:

```
val s = Source(List(data....)).keepAlive(15.seconds, () => Strict.TextMessage("heart beat"))
```

However, the akka-http api calls for a flow to handle the connection:

```
path("query") {
        parameter('session, 'package) {
          (session,packageId) =>
            val sg = getGraphManager(session)
            sg match {
              case Left(error) => complete(StatusCodes.BadRequest -> TSError(msg=error))
              case Right(gm) =>
                val tsFlow = new TSFlow(ksource, session)
                handleWebSocketMessages(Flow.fromGraph(tsFlow.flowGraph))

            }
         }
 }
```

Consequently, I never see the incoming source, so there's no opportunity to inject the keep-alive. How should I restructure things so I can inject a keep-alive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to control how connections are dropped server-side is to change the `idle-timeout` (see the docs [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/10.0.9/scala/http/common/timeouts.html#idle-timeouts) and [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/10.0.9/scala/http/websocket-support.html#example)).

You can set

```
idle-timeout = infinite
```

to completely disable the timeout.

If you want to use keep alive messages, they need to be sent from the client side. The `.keepAlive` combinator is the easiest way to get them if your client is based on Akka Streams.